# Swipe over multiple UIButtons to highlight/select

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to be able to swipe over a series of buttons. This should select and highlight all buttons which were swiped over. A bit like drawing a line in a crossword. Has anyone had any success with anything like this? I need to write this programmatically in obj-c.. Any help would be appreciated.

Would using the 'UIControlEventTouchDragEnter' method help at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've managed to solve my problem thanks to NO-ONE's help! ;)

The way to do this is via the 'touchesBegan' and 'touchesEnded' methods. Also, the UIButton class I was using must be subclassed to override the mentioned methods with the following code:

```
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

..otherwise the UIBUtton consumes the touch events like the hungry animal it is.
Most other views will not need to be subclassed.

I am now able to receive touch events from my subclassed UIButtons and with some further implementations can perform a swiping feature.
Hope this helps others!